# how to add specific element to the array of arraylist

Tags: java

```
ArrayList<int[]> arl = new ArrayList<int[]>();
int a1[] = {1, 2, 3};
arl.add(0, a1);
```

How do I set an element value at a specific position like we do in 2d array as `ar1[0][2]=5`  in this code if we want to reset the value 3 to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define you `arl` as

```
ArrayList <int []> arl = new ArrayList <int []> ();
arl.add (0, new int [] {1, 2, 3});
```

and do like this:

```
arl.get (0) [2] = 5;
```

Comment: +1 for right answer. But I think it's good way if you do `List <int []> arl = new ArrayList <int []> ();`